# Column headings not showing up using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to import a small csv file which seems to work out.   When I look at the imported file i see all the data in a nice format with all the column headings and the corresponding data.   My issue is when I try to run the command report.(tab key) for instance I only see a few column headings in that list.   When I manually try to run report.RouterName I get an error.  The column headings that I *do not* see are: RouterName, Router_Type, Switch_IP and CPU.    If I run report.columns I see all of the column headings listed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: report = pd.read_csv("/Users/iron-horse/Documents/Python_Files/Workbook1.csv")

In [3]: report
Out[3]: 
  RouterName   Router_Type    Switch_IP       Software_Rev CPU       \
0  BRPTCT0101  GX-550           10.10.50.7    09.01.01.20        NP   
1  BRPTCT0106  CBX-500 (3 PS)   10.10.50.56   09.01.01.20       SP    
2  BRPTCT0107  GX-550           10.10.50.35   09.01.01.20        NP   
3  BRPTCT0102  CBX-500 (3 PS)   10.10.50.67   09.01.01.20        SP   

   Card_Fill  Trunks  LogicalPorts  CircuitEndpoints Region Area  
0          8       2            22               795     CT   NE  
1         13       6            74               905     CT   NE  
2         12      34            59              2039     CT   NE  
3         11       4            45               815     CT   NE  

In [4]: report.columns
Out[4]: Index([u'RouterName ', u'Router_Type   ', u'Switch_IP     ', u'Software_Rev', u'CPU     ', u'Card_Fill', u'Trunks', u'LogicalPorts', u'CircuitEndpoints', u'Region', u'Area'], dtype='object')

In [5]: report.RouterName
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a89b0f0e8073> in <module>()
----> 1 report.RouterName

/Users/iron-horse/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1841                 return self[name]
   1842             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1843                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1844 
   1845     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'RouterName'

In [6]:
```

Answer (score 3):

it's spacing. look at the exact column name. what is it?

a fix would be to do something like:

```
df.columns = map(str.strip, df.columns)
```

and then you could access the column name like `df.RouterName`

if you want to do it as is, you have to do `df['RouterName ']`

Comment: thanks acushner. So are you saying that the actual column spacing is causing that?   I wouldnt think that the physical width of a column would matter.  I will see about making the changes you have suggested.

Comment: not width per se, but the column name itself includes whitespace. so, e.g., `'abc'` is different from `' abc                          '`

Comment: ascushner, you were correct it was due to the "white" spaces in the column name. I took a spreadsheet that I had and converted it to a csv file and somehow in the process had spaces in each field. Wouldn't think that it would matter if there were while spaces after the name but apparently it did. I was googling everything I could think before posting on here. Thanks again!!

Comment: you got it. if you want to accept the answer to close it (and give me sweet, sweet rep) that would be great.